# Spring Junit with session object - not visible in Controller

Tags: java, spring, session, junit, spring-junit

Simple Test class have the following:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;
@Autowired
MockHttpSession session;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void before() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

@Test
public void testSetSomeType() throws Exception {
    this.session.putValue("PREV_PAGE_VAL", "FOO");
    System.out.println(this.session.getAttribute("PREV_PAGE_VAL")); //FOO is there, so far so good, but in the controller, its null
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/setSomeType").param("someType", "ACCESS_ONLY").session(session)
                .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
    ResultActions result = this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

..

And the Controller class has the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setSomeType", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody AppResponse setSomeType(@RequestParam(value = "someType") final String someType, final HttpSession session) {
    //someType has "ACCESS_ONLY"
    //session.getAttribute("PREV_PAGE_VAL"); is null, expecting FOO
}
```

Question: Why is session not having the FOO? What is missing?
..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Spring can automatically link a `MockHttpSession` (I also don't know where you're autowiring it from).

You can add it manually.

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/setSomeType")
            .param("someType", "ACCESS_ONLY")
            .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .session(session);
```

Alternatively, you can use `sessionAttr(String, Object)` to add session attributes individually.

Comment: huh! shame on me, that was the issue. I was using putValue and getAttribute. Guess I just needed a second eye :) Thanks @Sotirios